# WPF Binding not being updated Properly

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am having the most frustrating issue I have had in a while, I have setup as below, and recently it has stopped working on the clients computers for no reason(or no reason that I can tell note I haven't changed any code in this section for months and this has only started happening in the last week) what is happening is the the Text is not becoming visible when the user hits edit, the weird thing is is that it works 100% in debug, release (using VS2010) and having the program installed on my computer, and I am stumped I can seem to replicate at all on my own computer. My question is simply (albiet a little vague) can anyone point or tell me where to look it debug this?

View Model Section (just a typical binding):

```
    private bool _editingSpecifications = false;
    public bool EditingSpecifications
    {
        get { return _editingSpecifications; }
        set
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("In EditingSpecifications property PRE: "+value);
            if (_editingTraceSpecifications == value)
                return;
            _editingSpecifications = value;
            base.OnPropertyChanged("EditingSpecifications");
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("In EditingSpecifications property POST");
        }
    }
```

View:

```
  <TextBox Visibility="{Binding Path=EditingSpecifications, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis2}}" Text="{Binding Path=Specifications, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="262">...</TextBox>
```

And Converter:

```
 public class BoolToVisibiltyConverter2 : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (targetType != typeof(Visibility))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The target must be a Visibility");
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show((bool)value + " :BoolToVisibiltyConverter2");
        if ((bool)value)
            return Visibility.Visible;
        return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((Visibility)value == Visibility.Visible)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Its a MVVM setup where the ViewModel binds to the view on demand(ie when the user wishes to edit etc), the code above is all I feel is relevant (if you need more just ask :)), as you can see I have some messagebox pop up and from that I get this scenario:
The user loads the **first** View hits edit messagebox pops up
1) "In EditingSpecifications property PRE: "+value
2) (bool)value + " :BoolToVisibiltyConverter2"
3) "In EditingSpecifications property POST"
Everything works as expected, however on loading a **second** view (note this could even be the same view just closed and reopened) 
1) "In EditingSpecifications property PRE: "+value
**2) (bool)value + " :BoolToVisibiltyConverter2"** - but not this, so in otherwords the converter is not called on the second and any subsequent attempts to edit the specifications.
3) "In EditingSpecifications property POST"
If you hit edit again on the same box you only get:
1) "In EditingSpecifications property PRE: "+value - which is kinda expected.

**EDIT- Bit More Detail**
The problem being that only on first edit attempt will the Textbox become visible, and will not become visible on any subsequent requests after closing and opening the view :/ And I feel it has something to do with the binding not being updated from the ViewModel on update request but I can't replicate it.

And the only way to reset this is to close and open the program, and as I stated before I can only replicate this behaviour on the clients computer and never on my own. So could anyone please tell me or point me in any direction of where to look please.

Comment: Add a messagebox to the `OnPropertyChanged()` method to see whether the event is actually raised (ie. if there is anyone handling it)

Comment: Please show your code for "loading a second view" and "hit edit".
And this is not your problem, but I think "if (_editingTraceSpecifications == value)" should be "if (_editingSpecifications == value)"

Comment: haha yea sorry I renamed a lot of things before I posted it on here so its not going to a naming issue, probably just missed it when I renamed :) I have ended just rewriting the segment of code and it works fine now frankly I didn't change anything taht I feel could have affected it except maybe one thing but that wasn't explaining why it would work fine on my computer but not the other :/

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar problem introduced in WPF 4.0 when navigating backwards to a page: the page would be displayed correctly, but the bindings wouldn't work. The workaround was to wrap the contents of the View into a DataTemplate, so that the View would be instantiated anew every time it was displayed.

Another thing you could try is setting the DataContext to null and then back to the ViewModel, in order to force a reset of the bindings.

By the way: why are you writing your own BooleanToVisibilityConverter? There is one in System.Windows.Controls ...

Comment: I decided to just rewrite that segment of code, and really in scope of things I didn't really change anything :/ but now it works so I am just going to leave it as is, but the thing that really bugged me was why it worked fine on my computer, but not on another :/ As for the Datacontext I already set it up to do that before :) As for the BooleanToVis, there is? When i first started looking for something like that I couldn't find anything (except for custom ones) about it so just just decided to write my own it was simple enough for what I needed, msdn documentation FTW :P